# How should I generate a Rhodes extension from a Ruby gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rhomobile

I know there is no direct support for Ruby gems in the Rhomobile framework. I have read their (sparse!) documentation to migrate in gem support through [extensions](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/extensions), but I cannot for the life of me figure out how exactly this should be implemented.

Besides the document linked above being very disjointed, what I can find can't be easily translated to what I need. I am trying to bring [devise](https://rubygems.org/gems/devise) into my app, but the gem structure is very hierarchical and the example given in the Rhomobile documentation suggests that a given library should be a singular `.rb` file.

The exact example given is as follows:

```
Assuming your application is called “mynewapp”, create a directory 
under app called lib (or whatever you wish to call it):

$ cd mynewapp
$ mkdir app/lib

$ cp /path/to/my_lib.rb app/lib/my_lib.rb
```

Then just require `lib/my_lib` in a given file within my app. Eg:

```
require 'lib/my_lib'
```

To translate to the devise gem, my assumption is that I couldn't do something similar, but would instead have to flatten the directory structure out in some way before I could use it. Is that the case or am I missing something? That's **a lot** of re-writing code...

Also, if anyone knows of any kind of guide to adding gems to the Rhodes framework, I would love to see it! I've looked through most of the official documentation and some non-official and nothing seems to address this at all.

Answer (score 1):

Wow. I don't know how I overlooked this, but it's really simple and nothing like what I was assuming.

> If you are using Rhodes via the RubyGems installation, you must add external Ruby libraries to your RubyGems installation directory for the ‘rhodes-framework’ gem. Your RubyGems installation directory can be found with `gem env` in a terminal.

[From the same page linked in question.](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/extensions)

My paths didn't match what was listed in that document because I'm using [RVM](https://rvm.io/), but I just ran `find / -name rhodes-*` and just looked for the one followed by `/lib/framework`.